# Not able to find port number for tomcat process on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, tomcat, netstat

I am not able to find a port number for running Tomcat server on Ubuntu
i.e. `netstart -anp | grep 'tomcat'` but not getting any output.

Comment: What happens if you leave out the _grep_?

Comment: The word `tomcat` is not in the output of `netstat`. You need to find its process ID and grep it.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to `grep` for `java` and not `tomcat`, as the process binary is `java` and not Tomcat.

If you'd like to find the PID for the process to make things easier (e.g. if you have lots of Java processes on the server), you can do this:

```
ps aux | grep catalina
```

This will show you your various Tomcat processes. Each one will have a system property on the command-line like this:

-Dcatalina.base=/path/to/your/tomcat

Note that there is also `catalina.home` which may be different. If they are different, it is `catalina.base` which is the correct one, which contains your server's `conf/server.xml` which controls the server.

Once you have that PID, you can `netstat -plan | grep [PID]` to get your port number.

Or just look in /path/to/your/tomcat/conf/server.xml for any `<Connector>` elements, each of which should have a `port` specified.